# Executing a method multiple times using a lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

What is the easiest and quickest way to execute a code block multiple times using a lambda expression in Java 8?
For example, a code that will replace the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
 doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an `IntStream.range`, but I don't see much advantage to this approach over the loop you are already using.

```
IntStream.range(0,20).forEach(i -> doSomething());
```

Comment: I was looking for something like that. Code is much cleaner this way. Thx.

Comment: One downside for it though is that it can't accept code which throws a checked exception. This is Java's fault since Consumer's Accept method can't throw a checked exception. baaah.

Comment: You could wrap the code which throws a checked exception in something which catches and rethrows as unchecked

Comment: or you could just use a for loop.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I completely agree with you. I really love Java 8's features and lambdas in particular, but IMHO there are things that are not made simpler by using lambdas. For loops are part of these things (especially when checked exceptions join the party).